# How can i repair a nail head size leak on a vertical cast iron sewer pipe in my basement

Tags: leak

House was built in 1958, the pipe is in good shape except for the small rusting now leaking nail size spot. I tried rustoleum, that is not helping. will epoxy work?

Comment: Need picture... always.

Comment: Any idea what caused the hole ?

Answer (score 7):

Epoxy is unlikely to make a lasting repair. What you need is a pipe repair clamp, which is a stainless steel band with a rubber gasket inside it - the "in place repair" type have a beveled overlapping edge so the clamp can be opened up and slipped onto the pipe, then clamped in place to seal the leak. They look similar to the "hubless coupling" clamps but those typically use a gasket that needs to have the pipe cut to slip onto it.

Comment: You also need a picture.

Comment: Trying to avoid appearing to endorse, shill or spam anyone's particular product, since there are darn few pictures of the things that are not from someone's catalog/website. Image searching the term is pretty effective.

Comment: This is the proper temporary fix, but the corrosion will continue to grow.  The only permanent fix is replacement of the section (but other areas of pipe may fail later on.  That's part of the fun of cast iron.

Answer (score 7):

I assume your leak is something along the lines of the following:

[image: leak in cast iron pipe]

Even though the hole may look small on the outside, it is like a tooth cavity, the corrosion on the inside is much larger. In most cases, even a small leak is an indication that the entire pipe needs to be replaced.